# In MFC, how do I tell if a CComboBox is enabled?

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

I see that you can enable/disable using the EnableWindow method, but how do I get it's current state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [IsWindowEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa1e993e(VS.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a GetWindowEnabled method and wasn't seeing it...still trying to get used to the naming conventions.